# Firefox developer edition won't accept cookies

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

I'm trying to switch over from Firebug to Firefox Developer Edition. I have a website that starts with a login page. The user enters his credentials, these are sent to a perl backend server, which sets a number of cookies with which the user can log in. In production this happens all over a secure connection, in my personal development environment that connection is not secure, since I'm testing toward a vm I'm running on my own pc. This has always worked with every browser. However with developer edition these cookies aren't set.

Do more people have this problem? Is there a way to fix this? Isn't the Firefox developer edition supposed to be exact a representation of Firefox? Because I don't want to have yet another browser to test my website for.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Based on this thread:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042859
I decided it is likely a problem with using "localhost". So I added an alias to me /etc/hosts file:

## /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 bb

Now instead of going to localhost:5000, I go to bb:5000. And so far the cookies are working.

Ubuntu 16.04
Firefox Developer Edition version 54.0a2